# Create new object for each array item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

The error:

> undefined method
>
> 'sub_agriculture_sub_agriculture_sub_agriculture_sub_agriculture_sub_agriculture_sub_agricultures_path'
>   for #<#:0x00007f5ec01b4b50'

**context**

I am building a student score system and currently having a resource issue (I think)
The relationships are defined as follows

```
Scorecard.rb
..
 has_one :sub_agriculture

sub_agriculture.rb
..
 belongs_to :scorecard

routes.rb
..
 resources :scorecards
 resources :sub_agricultures
```

Normally in `sub_agricultures_controller.rb` one would use;

```
def new     
  @sub_agriculture =  SubAgriculture.new
end
```

...because this results in

```
#<SubAgriculture id: nil, score: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, scorecard_id: nil>
```

I need to create several of these for their respective scorecards in a single entry form.

However only select `scorecards` have the `sub_agriculture` attached to them. (not all atudents take the subject agriculture). So I run a query on `Scorecard` where I `pluck(:id)` because I did not see it efficient using the entire active_record relations. I then end up with an array of ids like so; `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. This is a collection of scorecard_ids from the query.

So for each Id; I need to create a sub_agriculture score for it. For this case; six new sub_agriculture instances. For that I did this on `sub_agricultures_controller.rb`

```
def new    
    sc = Scorecard.scorecard_with_agriculture
  @sub_agriculture =  sc.map { |s|SubAgriculture.new(:scorecard_id => s) }

end
```

This spits this array out;

```
=>[#<SubAgriculture id: nil, score: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, scorecard_id: 1>, #<SubAgriculture id: nil, score: nil, created_at: nil
, updated_at: nil, scorecard_id: 2>, #<SubAgriculture id: nil, score: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, scorecard_id: 3>, #<SubAgriculture id:
 nil, score: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, scorecard_id: 4>, #<SubAgriculture id: nil, score: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, score
card_id: 5>, #<SubAgriculture id: nil, score: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, scorecard_id: 6>]
```

Which is what I had in mind but; the `/sub_agriculture/new` action hits me with this error

> NoMethodError in SubAgricultures#new
>
> undefined method
>   `sub_agriculture_sub_agriculture_sub_agriculture_sub_agriculture_sub_agriculture_sub_agricultures_path'
>   for #<#:0x00007f5ec01b4b50>

With this particular line in new form being highlighted

```
<%= form_with(model: sub_agriculture, local: true) do |form| %>
```

I need to create the six sub_agricultures in one form. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should use the "new" action for this since you move out from the conventions and rails excepts some things to happen. I would create two new actions: `bulk_new` and `bulk_create`

Add the routes for those actions:

```
resources :sub_agricultures do
  collection do
    get :bulk_new
    post :bulk_create
  end
end
```

New, when you pass a model to the form_with helper, it tries to infere the url from the array chaining the resources names and that's why you see that weird named route.

What you are doing is out of the conventions so you may need to fight a little with the inputs since rails won't be able to generate the proper names with that array, so you'll have to generate the input name prefix yourself, something like:

```
= form_tag bulk_create_sub_categories_path do |form|
  - sub_agricultures.each do |sub_ag|
    - input_name_prefix = "sub_agricultures[#{sub_ag.scorecard_id}]"
    div
      = hidden_field "#{input_name_prefix}[scorecard_id]", sub_ag.scorecard_id
      = label_tag "#{input_name_prefix}[score]", "Score for #{sub_ag.scorecard_id}"
      = number_field_tag "#{input_name_prefix}[score]", sub_ag.score
      # add some errors feedback too
```

Now, that form should submit a params hash like this:

```
{
  sub_agricultures: [
    1: {scorecard_id: 1, score: XX},
    2: {scorecard_id: 2, score: YY},
    etc...
  ]
}
```

So, in your `bulk_create` actions you'll have to do something like:

```
def bulk_create
  @sub_agricultures: []

  # loop through the sub_agricultures params array
  params[:sub_agricultures].each do |_, sub_ag_data|
    sub_ag = SubAgriculture.new(scorecard_id: sub_ag_data[:scorecard_id], score: sub_ag_data[:score])
    @sub_agricultures << sub_ag
  end

  # now I guess you want to validate all of them:
  if @sub_agricultures.all?(&:valid?)
    @sub_agricultures.each(&:save)
    flash[:notice] = "sub agricultures created"
    redirect_to somewhere_path
  else
    flash.now[:error] = "sub agricultures have errors"
    render action: :bulk_new
  end
end
```

Comment: I would'nt really trust `.all?(&:valid?)`. You probably want to wrap it in a transaction instead and check if everything is saved.

Comment: @max sure, but since the objects seems to only save a score value I tought it was simple enough to just check if all were valid, but a transaction is more error-proof for sure.

Comment: @arieljuod thank you; this definitely gets me closer to the intended solution.
Here is what I am getting so far;
`{"sub_agricultures"=>
  {"1"=>{"scorecard_id"=>{"1"=>""}, "score"=>"58"},
   "2"=>{"scorecard_id"=>{"2"=>""}, "score"=>"58"},
   "3"=>{"scorecard_id"=>{"3"=>""}, "score"=>"58"},
   "4"=>{"scorecard_id"=>{"4"=>""}, "score"=>"56"},
   "5"=>{"scorecard_id"=>{"5"=>""}, "score"=>"58"},
   "6"=>{"scorecard_id"=>{"6"=>""}, "score"=>"58"}}}`

and a NoMethodError at  @sub_agricultures []  in `sub_agricultures_controller.rb`

still working on it though

Answer (score 0):

`form_with` is not designed to create multiple records at once. The model keyword is passed to the polyphic url helpers so when you pass an array of models you get a nested route:

```
polymorphic_url([blog, post]) # => "http://example.com/blogs/1/posts/1"
```

Rails resolves this to `blog_posts_path` by calling `model_name.param_key` on the model instance.

Since you have a whole ton of records you get this ridiculus route `sub_agriculture_sub_agriculture_sub_agriculture_sub_agriculture_sub_agriculture_sub_agricultures_path`.

Even if that worked I doubt the form builder would work since its made to be used with single records instances. Not an array.

If you want to use nested attributes you need a model that wraps the nested attributes. So you need to either rethink your domain modeling (you can probally do a lot better) or use something like `<%= form_with(url: '/somepath') %>` and manually handle param binding and all that.

Handling mass-inserts in this ways is actually quite a bit more involved than just looping through an array. You have to ensure that all the records are valid and saved (think transactions) and handle passing the records back to the form if they are not. I would really try to avoid it if possible. There is a reason why its not part of the Rails conventions.

A good alternative is to use ajax to let the user create the lines one by one without leaving the page. You can do this with anatomical requests to just your normal run of the mill crud controller.

Comment: I understand the concern here; the request to have multiple entries at ago came about after the user experience was thought about. Its short numerical data; so making an entry, submitting it while another entry became available was too cumbersome for the eyes.

Comment: It doesn't have to be. If you're just saving in the background it can be completely transparent to the user. In fact posting a big form is not really that great either from a ux perspective.

Comment: since I already have the scorecards that take in these records; can I implement a Rails way using ajax? Like for the six scorecards above, have an ajax thing that infinitely scrolls to reveal more input? In this case, probably show four, then scroll down with ajax to reveal the other two?

Answer (score 0):

Your model relation can be improved. One score card(Report Card) will contain many subjects. So better redesign the relationships between those two classes.
[image]

Comment: One scorecard has_many subjects might load the DB with unnecessary 'nils'. For all existing cards (picture the one above) there will be a bunch of '0' records. Those consume indexes and time.
This solution only provides a scorecard that can only have subjects that that particular student takes. It also frees up space for statistics and school announcements.